# Не выполняется сценарий javascript

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Всем привет.

Есть PHP-обработчик, который заменяет HTML элемент при парсинге на свой кастомный.

```
        foreach($html->find('.hidewrap') as $value) {
        $value->outertext = '<div class="spoiler-wrapper">
            <div class="spoiler folded"><span>'.$value->children(0)->plaintext.'</span></div>
            <div class="spoiler-text">'.$value->children(2)->plaintext.'</div>
            </div>';
    }
```

После чего это все дело отдается через json. Собственно, в чем проблема. CSS к данным элементам применяется, но js сценарий выполняться не хочет.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.spoiler-text').hide();
        $('.spoiler').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideToggle();
        });
        });
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtfm api.jquery.com/on

```
$(document).on('click','.spoiler',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, не могли бы вы подсказать, как скрыть все элемент?

$('.spoiler-text').hide();

Ибо не скрывается.

Comment: @evansive скрывается. важнее в какой момент. в вопросе у вас .spoiler-text скрывается не по клику, а после загрузки страницы, т.е. сразу и один раз.

[demon](http://jsfiddle.net/9HhJt/)